# Is it possible to run Windows 10 in powershell/cmd only?

Tags: windows, headless

My development environment is Linux, however we have to support older Windows non-GUI software. The software is written in ASP.net (not core).

What I am hoping to be able to do is install Windows inside a VM and build/run the software within that VM. I don't need the UI so I am hoping to reduce the machine load by running Windows in a non-GUI mode.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use [Windows 10 IoT Enterprise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/windows-iot-enterprise). It supports a *[headless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/headlessmode)* mode (no UI).

> Windows 10 IoT Enterprise is a full version of Windows 10 that
>   delivers enterprise manageability and security to IoT solutions. [...]
>   It is a binary equivalent to Windows 10 Enterprise, so you can use the
>   same familiar development and management tools as client PCs and
>   laptops.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Windows Server Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-core/what-is-server-core) which is basically a stripped down variant of Windows server. But it's not possible to run Windows 10 without GUI. The only option is to kill explorer.exe, but that's not a very nice solution in my opinion.

Comment: I just need to run multiple shell screens and Msbuild - will this suffice?

Comment: It should be possible, but I'm not sure if the msbuild is installed by default. Maybe the answer of @splash is better. Use Windows 10 IoT Enterprise.